# Using a method with a custom type Feature parameter

Tags: java, parameters, custom-object

So I have three classes because I am trying to practice how to use custom type object and I ran into a problem. In my Auto class I made a method called showFeature() and I want the method to take in one parameter which would be the custom type Feature and it would print out the name and cost of the feature (Ex: The feature pants costs: 3000.0). But when I made the method it keep saying  expected on the last quotation of Feature. Can anyone help me with this problem

```
public class Feature
{
    public String name;
    public double cost;
    public Feature(String s, double d){
        //step 1
        name = s;
        cost = d;
    }
    //step 4
}
```

```
public class TestAuto
{
   public static void main(String args[]){
    //instantiate an Auto object
    Auto at = new Auto("AMG", 73.5);

    //instantiate a Feature object
    Feature fe = new Feature("Leather Seat", 3000);

    //execute method addFeature with Feature object
    at.showFeature(fe);

    //prepare a new Feature object for receving information
    Feature fe1 = new Feature("", 0);

    //Run method discountValue with a feature and a new value
    fe1 = at.discountValue("GPS", 15000, 0.2);

    //print out the object
    System.out.println(fe1);
   }
}
```

```
public class Auto
{
    public String name;
    public double size;
    public Auto(String s, double sz){
        name = s;
        size = sz;
    }
    //step 2: method showFeature()
    public Feature showFeature(Feature){
        
        System.out.println("The feature " +s+" costs: "+d);
        
    }
    public Feature discountValue(String s, double c, double d){
    //Step 3: method to give discount on cost
        double f = c - d;
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: You code doesn't compile. Please supply something at least in a working state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you have it taking in a Feature with no variable attached. You have a feature class which creates a feature object that takes in a String and a Double, which is probably why there is an expected note, because you haven't supplied the feature with any inputs.

```
//step 2: method showFeature()
public Feature showFeature(Feature f){
    
    System.out.println("The feature " + f +" costs: "+ f.cost);
    
}
```